# How to stop Guided Access interfering with navigation buttons

Tags: ios, button, navigation, uinavigationbar, guided-access

When Guided Access is enabled, buttons on a UINavigationBar don't activate when you tap on one side of them (and the button does confusingly still dim and highlight as you tap).

You can actually see it in the iOS built-in apps. eg:

iPhone (iOS 9.2.1) > Contacts > triple-click the Home button to start Guided Access

Now pick a contact, then try to go back by tapping near the “s” of “< All Contacts”. You will see “All Contacts” dim and restore as you tap it, but it doesn’t actually activate.
This does not happen when not in Guided Access.

Can anyone else confirm this is a problem?

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround in iOS to avoid this?

I have an app that needs to work properly in Guided Access mode.

UPDATE 15/JUN/2016: The same problem happens in "Single App Mode"
eg Apple Configurator > Set an iPhone or iPad as Supervised > Start Single App Mode > Choose the "Contacts" app and as above see that trying to go BACK using "< All Contacts" doesn't work when you tap near the "s".

Comment: you mean with voiceover turned on? are you aware of how users who require voiceover will actually interact with your app?

Comment: No, nothing to do with VoiceOver - it's turned off